# How to deal with low survey response rate and hypothetical question about influence of people not responding?

Tags: bayesian, survey, data-imputation, pymc

**Background:**

Imagine you are running a survey, asking 1000 random people: "do you like blue marbles?"

Now, 200 people respond. 150 say yes, 50 say no.

If I had only sent that survey to only those 200 peoples, I know how to make pymc3 give me a Bayesian estimation of the proportion of people that like blue marbles.

However, in this case 800 people did not respond to the survey. When I present my estimation results I can say that am assuming those 200 are a random sample under assumption that people responding was random.

**Problem scenario:**

But say when someone is reviewing my results, they have a question: "Let's suppose that people that did not like blue marbles are twice (or any other number) as likely not to respond. How does your result change?"

So far, all tutorials I can find on data imputation assume some columns are missing, not entirely not responding to a survey

**Questions:**

1. How do I handle that in a Bayesian way?
2. Can I tell pymc3 to handle that?

**Note**: Since I am self-learning pymc3 I prefer answers using it, but I really do not mind if you know how to solve this using, for example, R and Stan or Julia and Turing.

Comment: How would you know why people didn't answer if they didn't answer? This is a much more fundamental problem, Bayes won't help you here.

Comment: I don’t want to know why the didn’t answer, I want to assume they didn’t because they dislike blue marbles more than those who did answer